# Can not resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-profiles, maven-deploy-plugin

I just download spring mvc maven project form git and run `mvn clean pacakage`, I got below error

```
D:\OpenJDK\OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u265b01\jdk8u265-b01\bin\java.exe "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\Non motor DMS - UAT new\main" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57987:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.2.4 clean validate compile package verify install site deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.saman:chamara >-----------------------
[INFO] Building saman:chamara 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.203 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-29T19:18:33+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:pom:2.7 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.80.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

And In maven plugins it shows below error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORYLl.png)

when I open the project I got below error in red color

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
```

And project also can't open

How to resolve this and open the app

Comment: Looks like a network issue: `repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.80.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> `... apart from that your command line with `clean validate compile package verify install site deploy` is simply wrong... furthermore I recommend to upgrade your IDEA IntelliJ version...

Comment: @khmarbaise Is it ok to delete .iml file or any intellij related files

Comment: Sure. You simply have to import another time into IDEA IntelliJ...

Comment: @khmarbaise what do you mean by network issue? and what is this repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.80.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect ->

Comment: The network does not work as it should be working... If you are in corporate network it could be something like firewall/proxy issue...

Comment: @khmarbaise can I manually download and add it to .m2 folder?

Comment: technically you can but the plugin has also a number of dependencies.... so I wouldn't recommend it ....do you have repository manager in your environment?